# How could I format (mainly, change size) drop down menus (select) in a form?

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, drop-down-menu

I have some select options in a form, but I'd like to make them bigger and more squarish, the default browser look doesn't really work for what I want to do.

Is there an easy way to style forms in the manner I'd like? I've been looking into it on my own, but I can't find anything. I assume there must be some nice CSS tutorials out there or some jQuery plugins?

Thanks!

EDIT: Figure, right after I ask this, I stumble on http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/ I'm loving the look of the plugin, but again, is there a way to make the text (and therefore the display box) larger?

EDIT 2: The main thing I'm looking for is the ease of choosing a size of the select element (and font size).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form elements are kinda bitchy. Each browser render differently (just think at radio/checkboxes alignment!)

However, you can style by using [Niceform](http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/demo/v20/niceforms.html) or any other similar library.

Comment: Haha, yeah the general consensus out there seems to be that forms are a hassle when it comes to design. I apprecite you linking that library, it seems to be what I need!

Comment: Shoot, it doesn't seem to have the ability to change the height